# How do I check whether a file is available to download?

Tags: macos, applescript

The following code generates a link to download the HD file from a site every day, but it doesn't know how to determine whether the link is valid or not. How do I check the validity of the link?

```
set z to ""
set d to tid(tid(short date string of (current date), "/"), "")
set w to weekday of (current date)
set r to 10

if d > 20000000 then
    set Prefix to d as text
else
    set Prefix to (d + 20000000) as text
end if

on tid(input, delim)
    set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, delim}
    if class of input is list then
        set output to input as text
    else
        set output to text items of input
    end if
    set my text item delimiters to oldTID
    return output
end tid

set x to 1
set y to ((characters 1 thru 4 of Prefix) as string)

repeat with i from 1 to r

    if i < 10 then
        set x to "0" & i
    else
        set x to i
    end if

    set c to "http://streaming.hkjc.edgesuite.net/hdflash/racingfocus/" & y & "/" & Prefix & "/" & x & "/" & "chi/racingfocus_" & Prefix & "_" & x & "" & "_chi_2500kbps.mp4"

    set z to z & c & "" & return & return
    set i to i + 1

end repeat

display dialog z
```

Comment: Hi Varela… I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking. Can you try to make it a little more clear what part you need help with?

Comment: @TJLuoma I've (hopefully) made OP's question more clear.

Comment: You could try downloading the file and if it downloads, the link is valid.

Comment: If you need specific coding advice, please reduce your code sample to the part where you want do download the file. How you build the URL isn‘t relevant for the question.

Comment: An easy way is to use `curl` and then trap for the `404` error if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Right now your code sample doesn‘t include the part where you actually access/download the file. If you need support in handling any errors occurring in this step, please include the relevant part of the code.

Comment: look at the following link generated and access the the server … http://streaming.hkjc.edgesuite.net/hdflash/racingfocus/2018/20181101/01/chi/racingfocus_20181101_01_chi_2500kbps.mp4

if it fails, I got this return from the server each time exactly these same words : File not found." why not figure out some codes could tackle the returned message ?

Comment: how to code : curl and the program can check for the 404 error itself ?

Answer (score 4):

I usually check the HTTP Code and then run from there. Since this is tagged AppleScript here is an example handler I wrote:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

set foundMP4 to my checkStream(c)

on checkStream(passedStream)
    try
        set serverCommand to "curl -o /dev/null -Iw '%{http_code}' " & passedStream
        set serverResult to do shell script serverCommand
        if serverResult does not start with "2" then
            return false
        else
            return true
        end if
    on error serverResult
        display dialog "Ran into issue checking server status, with error: " & serverResult with title "Server Check"
    end try
end checkStream
```

After you check the HTTP code you could write for the script to download the file.

Comment: Nice solution. +1

Comment: +1 but sometimes websites are stupid and don't feature the correct error codes. Better solution would be to test if there is an actual file available to download.

Answer (score 0):

*If* the server supports it, you should be able to do something like this:

```
curl -sfLS --head http://www,whatever.tld/this/path/here.ext
```

*(That’s supposed to be two `-` before `head` even if it got turned into an em-dash!)*

And then you want to check the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Something like this would work:

```
URL="http://streaming.hkjc.edgesuite.net/hdflash/racingfocus/2018/20181101/01/chi/racingfocus_20181101_01_chi_2500kbps.mp4"

    # the 'tail -1' means "If there are more than one, just give me the last one"
    # which you'll need in case of redirects.
CODE=$(curl -sL --head "$URL" | awk -F' ' '/^HTTP/{print $2}' | tail -1)

case "$CODE" in
    404)
        echo "Not found: $URL"
    ;;

    200)
        echo "Found! $URL"
    ;;

    *)
        echo "Unknown Response ($CODE) for $URL"
    ;;

esac
```

Comment: This would be a pretty good answer if you hadn't supplied the solution in a completely different scripting language than the one the OP is using with no details on how to adapt that code into her language of choice.

Comment: True. I did not recognize it as AppleScript at the time when I read it (nor did I see the tag that's there now.)